# Akka: when is it safe to send a message

Tags: scala, akka

I am creating an actor via:

```
system.actorOf(Props(....))
```

or

```
system.actorOf(SmallestMailboxPool(instances).props(Props(....))).
```

I usually block the thread calling `system.actorOf` till `actorSelection` works.
`Await.result(system.actorSelection("/user/" + name).resolveOne(), timeout.duration)`

I am wondering if this is at all needed or I can immediately start using the `actorRef` and send (tell) messages to the actor/actor pool.

So the question boils down to, if I have an `actorRef`, does that mean the mailbox is already created or it might so happen that the messages I sent immediately after calling `system.actorOf` might get dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drill down the the implementation of `system.actorOf`, you see a call to a method names `makeChild`. Internally, this utilizes a lengthy method on the `ActorRefProvider` trait (internally using `LocalActorRefProvider`) called `actorOf`. This rather lengthy method initializes the child actor. Relevant parts are:

```
val props2 =
  // mailbox and dispatcher defined in deploy should override props
  (if (lookupDeploy) deployer.lookup(path) else deploy) match {
    case Some(d) ⇒
      (d.dispatcher, d.mailbox) match {
        case (Deploy.NoDispatcherGiven, Deploy.NoMailboxGiven) ⇒ props
        case (dsp, Deploy.NoMailboxGiven)                      ⇒ props.withDispatcher(dsp)
        case (Deploy.NoMailboxGiven, mbx)                      ⇒ props.withMailbox(mbx)
        case (dsp, mbx)                                        ⇒ props.withDispatcher(dsp).withMailbox(mbx)
      }
    case _ ⇒ props // no deployment config found
}
```

Or if a `Router` is explicitly provided:

```
val routerDispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup(p.routerConfig.routerDispatcher)
val routerMailbox = system.mailboxes.getMailboxType(routerProps, routerDispatcher.configurator.config)

// routers use context.actorOf() to create the routees, which does not allow us to pass
// these through, but obtain them here for early verification
val routeeDispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup(p.dispatcher)
val routeeMailbox = system.mailboxes.getMailboxType(routeeProps, routeeDispatcher.configurator.config)

new RoutedActorRef(system, routerProps, routerDispatcher, routerMailbox, routeeProps, supervisor, path).initialize(async)
```

Which means that once you get back an `ActorRef`, the mailbox has been initialized and you shouldn't be scared of sending it messages.

If you think about the semantics of what an `ActorRef` stands for, it would be a bit pointless to provide one with an `ActorRef` which is partly/not initialized. It would make system guarantees weak and would make the programmer think twice before passing messages, which is the opposite desire of the framework.

Comment: That does make sense. I would expect a future instead of an ActorRef if the return of system.actorOf is not usable immediately. Thanks a ton.